# Qt resize: setting fixed size for widgets and need to resize depending on the screen size

Tags: qt, resize

I'm developing a desktop app in Qtcreator that needs to be resized according to the screen size. I already know how to obtain the screen size. However, I'm not developing it fullscreen yet, because I want to set an optimum intermediate size and resizes it later.

I've set fixed sizes to the parent window (i.e, 1370px,768px) and to all the children widgets using the "setfixedsize()" function and the app looks great. But now I'm setting another fixed size to parent window (i.e, 1920px,1080px) and the children widgets isnt expanding proportionally. I want them to expand and reduce according to the size of parent window.

Am I doing right in setting fixed sizes to all children widgets? Or Is that the problem? What's the correct way to develop an app in Qt with this resize ability?

Thanks guys.

Ps: Sorry about the english.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a fixed size only for the main widget. The size of the child widgets should be determined using layouts.

```
QWidget* mainWidget = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout* vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout(mainWidget);
QWidget* firstChildWidget = new QLabel("first widget");
QWidget* secondChildWidget = new QLabel("second widget");
QWidget* thirdChildWidget = new QLabel("third widget");
vBoxLayout->addWidget(firstChildWidget);
vBoxLayout->addWidget(secondChildWidget);
vBoxLayout->addWidget(thirdChildWidget);
mainWidget->setFixedSize(400, 400);
mainWidget->show();
```